# Windows 11 Network computers icons are not showing in Explorer but can be explored typing the adress in adress bar

Tags: networking, windows-11

I have 4 computers with Windows 11 Pro latest update.

All are configured in a Private Network , with the same Workgroup. All the network discover and sharing options are enabled and configured correctly.

But if i open Network in explorer , the computers icons are not showing.If i type the computer adress in adress bar i can enter and explore that computer.

What can i do in order to show computer icons?

Comment: My mapped drives in Windows 11 show in the tree under This PC just below the files in the tree. Are they there for you?

Comment: @John I have no mapped Drives. I want just to see network computers icons in Explorer-Network.

Comment: I have one machine with mapped drives (batch file to connect) and one machine where I browsed and used the files. In both machines I see the drives under This PC

Comment: Make sure that the following services are started:

1) DNS Client
2) Function Discovery Resource Publication
3) SSDP Discovery
4) UPnP Device Host